# Animate / apply Transition addClass and removeClass in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am new to jQuery & javascript and making a simple slider by adding and removing class 'active' on next slide which is working fine but seems ugly because there is no animation. Is there any way to animate the process of adding and removing a class? Like:

```
$('#next').on('click', function(){
    $('div.active').removeClass('active', duration: 500ms).next().addClass('active', duration: 500ms);})
```

At [Jquery documentation website](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) I have seen that there is an animate function which is used to animate things. Is it possible to use that function in my case?

Update: I have also tried to apply the CSS transition on div and div.active which is not working.

Css:

```
   .slider div {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    div.active {
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: You can search for transition in css. Then adding and removing that class can trigger that animation. And yes you can use jquery animation function it has plenty of properties you can set just read their docs it has exameples of how to do it.

Comment: @user5014677 I have applied css animations but they are not working.

Comment: You can't transition the `display` property...that's probably at the heart of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments of different users I came to know that css transition can not be applied on `display: none` elements. So instead of display none I applied `height 0px; opacity: 0;` which worked fine for me.

```
.slider img{
 height: 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 display: block;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease;
 -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease;
 -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease;
 -o-transition: opacity 2s ease;
 transition: opacity 2s ease;
}

.slider img.active{
 height: 360px;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease;
 -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease;
 -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease;
 -o-transition: opacity 2s ease;
 transition: opacity 2s ease;
}
```

Thanks to the creator of [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/kujiwuzuce/edit?html,css,js,output) which gave me this idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
.active {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why the transition is not working. I have tried them.

Comment: What do you mean by updating the HTML? see my code: https://jsfiddle.net/L0ar3r86/2/

Answer (score 0):

you cant really animate addClass or removeClass but you could add a transition

but you can use some css:

```
.item {   
   opacity: 0
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.item.active{
   opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: `.slider div{
 display: none;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

div.active{
 display: inline-block;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}`

Transition is not working. I don't know why.

Comment: use .slider div.active instead of div.active

Comment: Didn't work. Even I removed the divs and used .slider img. here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L0ar3r86/2/

Comment: its because of the display, you need to use visibility instead, 
something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/za3a52s0/
its not a perfect solution but you should be able to make use of it

Comment: Thanks for telling me this secret :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animation, in your case you can use transitions
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: You can add  .slider img{ width:0px} and img.active{ width:480px;}

Answer (score 0):

Add animation class:

```
$(".otp-wrapper").addClass('test');
```

Remove animation class:

```
$(".otp-wrapper").removeClass('test');
```

Stylesheet:

```
.test {
        animation: shake 0.5s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }

@keyframes shake {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
        25% {
          transform: translateX(5px);
        }
        50% {
          transform: translateX(-5px);
        }
        75% {
          transform: translateX(5px);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
      }
      .err-msg{
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:400;color: red;
      }
```

Refernece: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shake_image.asp